# Migrar programa c# con report viewer

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net, stored-procedure, report

Tengo un programa en windows forms c# .net que utiliza reportviewer para generar una cotizacion dependiendo el resultado de ciertos procedimientos almacenados.
Ya termine el software y deseo instalarlo en la computadora del usuario final pero el reportviewer no tiene una cadena de conexion o algo similar para cambiar los parametros
Alguien sabe que puedo hacer?

Comment: esto no es migrar.. esto es instalar... y tu cadena de conexion no deberia estar en tu programa, deberia estar en tu archivo de configuracion....

Comment: deberias de pasarle el datasource al report desde tu programa y a la vez, conectar ese datasource con los datos del archivo de configuracion como dijo @gbianchi